# different layouts for each group in winJS ListView

Tags: javascript, listview, windows-8, winjs

i would like to know if it is possible to use different layouts for each group in a grouped ListView in windows 8 Metro Style Apps?

If yes, how?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, but not how you are wanting.

A grouped ListView uses the same item template unless you do some dynamic template swapping, which is possible, but I wouldn't recommend using template swapping to swap out entire groups. Swapping is better for using different templates for different types of item all mixed in together.

My recommendation is that at your ViewModel level you get your grouped list split out into different lists and build completely different ListViews for each. It sounds like you're talking about a hub page with sections and trying to get stylistic with them to look good, and if that's the case than you may want to get check out asymmetric ListViews or just use a Grid and populate it manually.

Comment: yes. i also wanted to to this. but i dont know how i can layout them horizontally.
i could position the lists with absolute position, but i dont know if this is a clean solution.

Comment: @Jeremy Foster Could you elaborate a bit on this? maybe with some code examples. this is a very common scenario I think as many apps in windows 8 use non homogeneous lists, like Bing Food (wines and recipes together) or Bing Health and fitness for example.

Comment: @Maurizio In denmark, the way I recommended before is obsoleted by Windows 8.1 now. Now the best way is to use a Hub control. The hub control makes laying an app out like the Bing apps _very_ easy. Instead of me recreating it, just download the MSDN sample from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HTML-Hub-control-sample-a15e5c2d and it should be clear.

Comment: @Jeremy Foster Thanks, I guessed so. I'm already on the way building my hub application. 8.1 is awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at Scenario 4 in the HTML ListView item templates sample:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-item-templates-7d74826f/view/SourceCode#content

That scenario shows how to create a template programmatically, which gives you more control over the output.

In a grouped items scenario, you could examine currentItem.group.key to determine which group you're dealing with, and provide different rendering for each group.

The downside is that, depending on how many different layouts you want, the code could get somewhat involved (though if you factor it for reusability by breaking each "group template" into its own function, that may help). But you should be able to accomplish what you want by building the template in code.

One thing to remember is that if you want different item sizes in your ListView, you'll need to provide a groupInfo for the ListView control, like so:

```
<div id="listView" 
    data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
    data-win-options="{ 
        itemDataSource: myCellSpanningData.dataSource, 
        itemTemplate: MyCellSpanningJSTemplate, 
        ...
        layout: { 
            groupInfo: { 
                enableCellSpanning: true, 
                cellWidth: 310, 
                cellHeight: 80 
            },
            type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout 
        } 
    }"
></div>
```

(I think my syntax above is correct...I'm combining some parts from the sample to make them more succinct, so the sample should be the final arbiter)

You can also set this programmatically, like so:

```
leaderListView.winControl.layout = new WinJS.UI.GridLayout({
    groupInfo: {
        enableCellSpanning: true,
        cellWidth: 200,
        cellHeight: 200
    }
});
```

Of note is that tiles can only be multiples of the cellWidth and cellHeight, so when you're planning your layout, take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, have a look at documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244627.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657974.aspx